# VBA: getting the active cell position relative to a specific range?

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have a `dim range B2:E7`. How do I find out the coordinates of an active cell relative to the range?

Comment: Cells have `Row` and `Column` properties.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you please explain a little more about what you are trying to do.  When you say coordinates are you referring to the X and Y Coordinates of a cell into some type of units (points/twips/pixels)?  What do you mean by relative to the range?

Comment: or are you talking in terms of `OFFSET`?

Comment: how do you find coordinates relative to a "range" ? which cell inside the range is considered as the anchor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the distance to the range from the active cell, this will work:

```
Sub colOffset()
  Dim testRange As Range
  Dim colLeft As Integer
  Dim colRight As Integer

  Set testRange = Range("B2:E7")
  colLeft = testRange.Column
  colRight = testRange.Column + testRange.Columns.Count - 1

  MsgBox "column-offset to first column: " & ActiveCell.Column - colLeft
  MsgBox "column-offset to last column: " & ActiveCell.Column - colRight
End Sub
```

Replace column with row to get the same for the rows.